# error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 36578304 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, pycharm

### Intro

I want to train a convolutional neural net to predict how many upvotes a picture posted to r/art will get on Reddit as a personal project.

I've downloaded 30000 pictures -> 18648 valid pictures and I named them using their score and post id so that posts would the same score wouldn't conflict (0_k0un69.jpg for example, only mildly important for the code snippet)

### Problem

I'm trying to create X, the input pictures array and Y, an array of the scores for neural net training. About 5.8% of the way through, I get the title error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-6sxsq0tp\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 36578304 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
```

The code that creates this error is the following:

```
path = "pics/"
#Get all file names
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
numpics = len(files)
#Store all image arrays and image names in a list
X = []
Y = []
counter = 0
for file in files:
    #Progress bar
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("Reading images into DataSets:  {:.1f}%".format((100/(numpics-1)*counter)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    counter+=1

    X.append(cv2.imread(f'{path}{file}'))
    Y.append(file.split(".")[0].split("_")[0]
```

It seems obvious to me that the problem is with how many big pictures I'm trying to process. Nonetheless, I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to avoid turning my pictures into grayscale/downsizing them, or if there's just a memory leak or problem with my code. If it helps, I was looking into using Global Pooling to handle variable image dimensions as [this medium post](https://medium.com/mindboard/image-classification-with-variable-input-resolution-in-keras-cbfbe576126f) and [a stack exchange post suggest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/445201). If it turns out that scaling wouldn't change the resolution after global pooling, please let me know because I have no idea.

### Attempted solutions

I heard that going from 32bit ->64 bit would help, but I'm not sure what that looks like for what I'm doing. I'm running this in a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm, and I checked that Pycharm is a 64 bit executable.

Some extra questions I have for comprehension:

1. The error message seems to occur on the Java Virtual Machine behind Pycharm or something like that because appveyor is not a user on my PC. That, or it's opencv related. Would running this without Pycharm maybe help?
2. Is this memory issue a RAM issue or a storage issue? I find it strange that the pictures themselves take up only ~22 GB of storage, but 6% of them trip up this error.

Comment: Do the math.  30,000 pictures of 36MB totals more than a terabyte.  You don't have a terabyte of memory.  I guarantee it.  There is a foolish notion that you need high-resolution pictures to train a model.  That's just wrong-headed.  You're looking for rough similarity.  Adding details does not improve the training.  Just reduce these pictures to, say, 96x96 and you'll get much better results.

Comment: Are these JPEGs?  Remember that JPEGs are highly compressed on disk.  When OpenCV reads them, it decompresses them to full size.